# “The data couldn’t be read because it is missing” error when decoding JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am getting the following error :

The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

When I run the following code:

```
var p = [Prevalentie]()
        let url = URL(string: "https://data.rivm.nl/covid-19/COVID-19_prevalentie.json")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in

            if let jsonData = data
            {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {
                    p = try decoder.decode([Prevalentie].self, from: jsonData)
                   print(p)


                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

            }

struct Prevalentie:Codable {
    var Date:String
    var prev_avg:Int
    
}

The json data:
{"Date":"2020-02-17","prev_low":693,"prev_avg":1067,"prev_up":1425,"population":"hosp","version":1}
```

I can get the value of date but not prev_avg.How can I solve this problem?
Thanks,

Comment: Print the `error` rather than `error.localizedDescription`. It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: As said, print `error` instead of `error.localizedDescription`, also show the code where you use `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: I get the "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing." error

Comment: No, if you do `print(error.localizedDescription)` => `print(error)`, you'll get a different  output in the console! The fix would be then `decode([Prevalentie].self` => `decode(Prevalentie.self`.

Comment: I get this error "keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "prev_avg", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 473", intValue: 473)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"prev_avg\", intValue: nil) (\"prev_avg\").", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: Well there's your answer.

Comment: But it is not normal the json has the "prev_avg" value.

Comment: Read the error. The 474th element in the array doesn't have a `prev_avg` value.

Comment: Denial won't help you here. It _is_ normal. You don't get to dictate reality; it's not your server. You just have to _accept_ reality, which is that _some_ of the JSON you are receiving lacks the `prev_avg` entry. Once you accept this, you can fix the problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your response objects has a `nil` value for `prev_avg` parameter.
to avoid this error, make `prev_avg` parameter as an optional ex: `let prev_avg:Int?`, or get back to your backend if you want to deal with `nil` parameters.